# Windows 8.1 AND Windows 10 doesnt stay in sleep mode / hibernate

Tags: windows-8, sleep, hibernate, windows-8.1

Ever since I upgraded from 8 to 8.1, my pc doesnt stay in sleep mode or hibernate. It does go into the respective mode but after about 3 seconds it always boots up again.

I noticed that it works fine with the LAN-cable unplugged.

I also want to emphasize that everything worked fine pre-update and I didn't change any settings or anything about my local network.

**Update:**
This also occurs on windows 10, the solution should be the same.

Comment: Sounds like you need to update the chipset drivers that support Windows 8.1

Comment: Ramhound can be right. Actually, update *all* your drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8.1 should update its drivers automaticaly, so I think the problem is elsewhere, more sounds like that the new driver have other default settings, and for example the Wake up over lan function is enabled by default.

If it only boot up again if the LAN cable is plugged in, maybe it waked up over lan by a wake up over lan package or because of some network activity (some card and it's drivers could make it, but I think you not have of this type of cards :) ). Try to disable the Wake up over LAN functions.

- Right Click on the Network icon on try
- Open Networ and Sharing Center
- Click on the left panel to the Change Adapter settings
- Select your LAN network (maybe it will called Ethernet)
- Right click on Properties (you need Administrator rights to open it)
- Click on Configure button
- Select Advanced (or Power Management) tab
- Search for **Shutdown Wake-On-Lan**, **Wake on Magic Packet**, **Wake on pattern match**
- ***Remember all of this default settings!!!***
- Disable this three item
- Restart computer
- Try to sleep the computer after restart

If it is work and your's PC stay in sleep mode then your PC get Wake on Messages from somewhere on your network.

If in not stay in sleep mode set all the setting to the previous value.

Comment: `Wake on pattern match` is the culprit here. All three options were enabled by default but disabling this one made the pc stay asleep. Apparently my router sends out some strange packages...